# How to export color changing animation from Blender to three.js

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I tried with gltf. My model changes color with changes in frames. So hope to get a positive response. Thanks in advance [from grey color[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atxiW.png) to [Red color][2]

Comment: It may also be helpful to have Blender scene file, pls upload somewhere to make it available.

Comment: @AlexKhoroshylov where should i upload ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at the `three.js` forum, it's currently not possible to export animation of materials to `glTF`. Might be possible in the future though.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-animate-alpha-in-blender-and-export-gltf-to-three-js/5428/2?u=mugen87